# Android device compatibility issue - what are some tools and strategies?

Tags: android, apk, compatibility, google-play

I have made an app that is incompatible with my client's device. It's not clear what part of my Android Manifest declarations is causing the incompatibility.

Is there:

(a) Some way of finding out *exactly* what part of the Android Manifest file makes the device incompatible?

Does the Google Play store list the causes somewhere? e.g. "ExampleApp requires that you have a screen size greater than xyz, your screen is too small" or "ExampleApp requires a camera which is not available on your device".

(b) Some tool that scans your Manifest file and spits out a big list of compatible devices?

As a last resort, I plan to loosen up my Android Manifest requirements, compile and publish my app to the play store and go to the "See supported devices" (http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en) section and then repeat the process with even looser requirements until I see my client's device listed.

That approach, however, seems particularly long-winded.

How do people usually solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the minimum sdk level to what you want it to be, then run android lint on your code to see i, or what is causing the incompatibility? If you think its because of something in the mainfest, could you post it?